# Alternate button text according to disabled/enabled status

Tags: jquery, html, validation, submit, form-submit

I have a form with jQuery validation which is working. Until you complete the form the submit button is disabled. When you complete the form the submit button is enabled.

My issue is that some users don't understand what a "disabled" button is and try to click. For this reason I need to change the text label of the button when disabled to "Fill the Form First!" and change again when the button is enabled to "SEND FORM"

I tried this:

```
$('#form input').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#form').valid()) {
    $(":submit").html('<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> SEND FORM');
  } else {
    $(":submit").html('<i class="fas fa-edit"></i> FILL THE FORM FIRST');           
  }
});
```

However this doesn't work and in IE11 I have a bug with "change", the button starts to "blink" the FontAwesome.

I'm not an expert in jQuery but maybe something like would work:

```
if $(":submit").prop('disabled', false);
{
  $(":submit").html('<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>  SEND FORM');
} else {
  $(":submit").html('<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>  FILL THE FORM FIRST');
}
```

Of course, as I said, I'm not an expert in jQuery, and this doesn't work too. Any ideas?

Comment: You may share your html as well.

Comment: why not bind it to your form submit event? If that doesn't work, then I think your looking for the keyup event for textbox inputs

Comment: hi @pete -  I try to bind to my validate event - did not works because there I have the keyup and change (here I have the IE11 issue) - and blur. My form submit event didn't work too because the submit button will be disabled until all form is validated by the validate event. When I valid all form, the button is enabled - but here I need to change booth text.. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `required` property in your inputs.
That prevents form sending if inputs are not filled.
Note that you could use placeholders to show that's required, too.

See snippet:

```html
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="John" value="" required>
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Doe" value="" required>
  <br>
  Gender:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="(Optional)" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

I am not sure that messages will be usefull, but, anyway…
You could use some JS and do something like this:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;

  // Note that I check only the "required" fields here
  $('[required]').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == '' )
        isValid = false;
  });
  
  if(isValid){
    $(":submit").html('<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> SEND FORM');
  }else{
    $(":submit").html('<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>  FILL THE FORM FIRST');
    $("form").on('keyup', validateForm);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" required>
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" required>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="validateForm();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi @takit-isy - first off all tks for your precious time and help. I will test here - maybe I need to make some changes (the msg must appears inside the button) - but I will return to you asap. tks a lot!!

Comment: @DANIEL No problem, I like doing this. :) I edited my answer with the html inside a button.

Comment: Hi @takit-isy! tks again! It is almost there.. just 1 thing (That's what I cannot do too - my "main issue") - We can "go to Fill the Form label" but we cannot "back to send form label" until we click.. The 100% OK is when I complete and it's all valid in the form I disable the button and as an enabled button again - it will appears the "SEND FORM" label to inform the user that he can now send the form. I don't know if you understand the issue.. First part is 100% ok disable the button / change to fill label -  but the "return" works only after you click.. and I need before - to inform the user

Comment: this is why in my code I use this: if ($('#form').valid())  - because I valid the form to enable the submit button..and return. But when I do this the fontawesome starts to blink because the valid method is "updating" in each change.. in IE11 this can "crash" the browse because of the video memory.. (my form is 10x the size of our example.. I have a catalog of courses to be choosen each one with 1 submit button.. then when all buttons stars to blink in IE11... crashes!)

Comment: @DANIEL I see what you mean. I modified my answer with `keyup` event so that we don't have to click somewhere to validate the form.

Comment: Hi @Takit-Isy! great! That's it - I Will test here because my form is a little more complex (I have text inputs, selects and a checked box) - I will return to you asap. tks a looooooot!